# WCF. Add Service Reference не видит сервис

Tags: c#, wcf

Вот контракт и класс, его наследующий

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimpleService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetUserName();
    }

 public class SimpleService : ISimpleService
    {
        public string GetUserName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is Authenticated: " +
                ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.IsAuthenticated);
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication Type: " +
                ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.AuthenticationType);
            Console.WriteLine("Username: " +
                ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name);

            return "Authenticated User Name: " +
                ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
        }
    }
```

Вот конфиг

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="SimpleService.SimpleService">
        <endpoint address="SimpleService"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="SimpleService.ISimpleService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Код консольного хоста, в котором находится конфиг

```
 public static void Main()
            {
                using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService.SimpleService)))
                {
                    host.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Host started @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Не ищет ни по адресу, ни с помощью Discover.

Comment: Сервис то перед тем как его искать у вас надеюсь запущен?

Comment: Делаю все согласно гайду, создал консольный хост и единожды его запустил. Расскажите, как еще можно это сделать

Comment: Покажите код консольного сервиса, к которому вы пытаетесь подключиться.

Comment: using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService.SimpleService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host started @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

Comment: Напишите код в вопросе.

Comment: А почему у вас адрес не указан у `ServiceHost`? Нужно как-то так: `new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService.SimpleService), baseAddress)`. Плюс необходимо включить публикацию метаданных, иначе `VS` не сможет сгенерировать код клиента.

Comment: Вылетает ошибка.System.ArgumentException: 'This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.'

Comment: Я в стандартной ситуации: все делал по гайду, скопировал код человека, у него получилось, у меня - нет. Единственное что гайд 2012 года.

Comment: @sp7 у него базовый адрес указан в конфиге же. И публикация метаданных у него включена

Comment: @EssenceZen Какой адрес сервиса вы вбивали? Попробуйте написать `http://localhost:8080/SimpleService?wsdl`

Comment: @EssenceZen может быть, все же признаетесь как именно вы пытались создать Service Reference? Ни у кого не получится вам помочь если вы будете отмалчиваться...

Answer (score 0):

Написал вам небольшой пример, как можно реализовать сервисную и клиентскую часть.

Сервисные контракты:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISimpleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetUserName(string name);
}

public class SimpleService : ISimpleService
{
    public string GetUserName(string name)
    {
        return name + " --> " DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Сервисная часть (хост):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService), new Uri("http://localhost:8088/hello")))
    {
        // Включае мпубликацию метаданных, для того что бы студия смогла 
        // сгенерировать клиент.
        var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Открываем сервисный хост.
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Сервис запущен {0}", new Uri("http://localhost:8088/hello"));
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для остановки сервиса.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Закрываем хост.
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Далее необходимо выполнить резервировании указанного URL адреса, делается это путем выполнения команды:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8088/hello user=UserName`

*Если в последствии необходимо будет выполнить удаление резервирования URL-адреса WCF следует воспользоваться командой:*

`netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:8088/hello`

---

Альтернативный способ обойтись без резервирования URL заключается в создании файла `app.manifest` и указания в узле `security` необходимого уровня привилегий:

```
<security>
    <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- Указываем необходимый уровень привилегий -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
   </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

---

Клиентская часть:

Затем в проекте с клиентской частью для автоматической генерации сервисного клиента делаем: `правый клик на References --> add service reference` - в поле `Address` указываем `http://localhost:8088/hello`. **Обратите внимание, что серверная часть перед этим уже должна быть запущена**.

После того, как студия создаст класс клиента, для взаимодействия с сервисом, просто его используем:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new SimpleServiceClient();
    Console.WriteLine(client.GetUserName("Вася"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам админские права для сервиса?.. Не учите плохому!

Comment: @PavelMayorov криминал то в чем? Для того что сервисная часть смогла зарегистрировать Uri `http://localhost:8088/hello` необходимы права администратора или вы знаете как это сделать по-другому?

Comment: Когда не хватает прав для работы - надо эти права выдать, а не запускать от админа все подряд! `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/hello user=...`)

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, не знал. Добавил данный способ в ответ.

Comment: Таким образом хост не запускается, ошибка : 'This collection already contains an address with scheme http.

Comment: @EssenceZen это рабочий пример. Вы можете с нуля создать 3 проекта: 2 консольных для клиента и хоста, и один проект типа `ClassLibrary` для сервисных контрактов. Затем скопировать приведенный код в эти проекты и запустить. Должно все запуститься, кстати в этом проекте файл конфигурации для хоста не используется, поэтому если он у вас есть удалите его.